# Touch within a pivot control

Tags: c#, touch, uwp

I have an elipsis, within a canvas that I would like to drag on the screen using touch input.

I can handle the events with pointer, and it works.

But if i place it within a Pivot control, the touch animation of the pivot control messes it up.

Is there a way of disabling the touch/drag behavior of the Pivot, while i am doing my own touch manipulation?

Using UWP in Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using manipulation or pointer events to move the ellipse?

Comment: Could you please post some codes to show what you are currently trying?